# Best way to use lightweight-charts package in nuxt project?

Tags: nuxt.js, lightweight-charts

I want to use lightweight-charts package in Nuxt project. I couldn't find any examples included in the Nuxt project. I did it with some methods but I don't know what is the best method. What is the correct way to run it on nuxt?

The use of the package on the site is as follows.

```js
import { createChart } from 'lightweight-charts';

const chart = createChart(document.body, { width: 400, height: 300 });
const lineSeries = chart.addLineSeries();
lineSeries.setData([
    { time: '2019-04-11', value: 80.01 },
    { time: '2019-04-12', value: 96.63 },
    { time: '2019-04-13', value: 76.64 },
    { time: '2019-04-14', value: 81.89 },
    { time: '2019-04-15', value: 74.43 },
    { time: '2019-04-16', value: 80.01 },
    { time: '2019-04-17', value: 96.63 },
    { time: '2019-04-18', value: 76.64 },
    { time: '2019-04-19', value: 81.89 },
    { time: '2019-04-20', value: 74.43 },
]);
```

https://github.com/tradingview/lightweight-charts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no example on this one because this is not related to Nuxt anyhow, neither really to Vue but more of a generic JS vanilla question.

Few points:

- it's great to import your component only when it's needed aka in your component (and not globally with [Nuxt plugins](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/plugins)), kudos for this one!
- usually, if you want to call an external function, you do this into `mounted()`, it depends on what you're doing there of course
- meanwhile, you should probably use [`$refs`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements) rather than `document.body` since we're in a state-based framework here
- `lineSeries.setData` could maybe be moved to `data` and injected afterwards

Answer (score 4):

This is could be something like

**plugins** folder create file: **chart.client.ts**

```
import { createChart } from 'lightweight-charts'

export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
    nuxtApp.createChart = createChart
})
```

**component** folder create file: **chart.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="lw-chart" ref="chartContainer"></div>
</template>

<script setup>
const nuxtApp = useNuxtApp();
const createChart = nuxtApp.createChart;

let chart;
const chartContainer = ref();

onMounted(() => {
    // Create the Lightweight Charts Instance using the container ref.
    chart = createChart(chartContainer.value,{
        layout: {
            background: { color: '#131F2B' },
            textColor: '#fff',
        },
        grid: {
            vertLines: { color: '#1E2F41' },
            horzLines: { color: '#1E2F41' },
        },
    });
    const areaSeries = chart.addAreaSeries();
    areaSeries.setData([
        { time: '2018-12-22', value: 32.51 },
        { time: '2018-12-23', value: 31.11 },
        { time: '2018-12-24', value: 27.02 },
        { time: '2018-12-25', value: 27.32 },
        { time: '2018-12-26', value: 25.17 },
        { time: '2018-12-27', value: 28.89 },
        { time: '2018-12-28', value: 25.46 },
        { time: '2018-12-29', value: 23.92 },
        { time: '2018-12-30', value: 22.68 },
        { time: '2018-12-31', value: 22.67 },
    ]);

    chart.timeScale().fitContent();
});

onUnmounted(() => {
    if (chart) {
        chart.remove();
        chart = null;
    }
});

</script>

<style scoped>
    .lw-chart {
        height: 400px;
    }
</style>
```

Yes, now you can use component all pages!